# How to configure MySQL under XAMPP to work with IPv6

Tags: mysql, xampp, ipv6

I have XAMPP v.3.1.0 and for testing purposes I need to connect to the MySQL database using IPv6 format.

How to configure MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Locate my.ini
- Change / uncomment `bind-address = ::          # for ipv6`
- Start mysql
- check in the console with the command `mysql -h ::1` if you manage to connect

Other resources:

1. [5.1 The MySQL Server :: 5.1.9 IPv6 Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ipv6-support.html)
2. [MySQL --bind-address=addr](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address)