# MySQL from XAMPP not starting anymore. Port is not the problem

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

I'm using XAMPP for Windows and MySql was working fine for the longest time, but now (after a Windows update I think) it crashes on start-up. When I click on "Start" in the Control Panel, I get a short flash of the PID and Port 3306 before it shuts down again.

This is the error I get in XAMPP:

```
09:14:09  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
09:14:09  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
09:14:09  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
09:14:09  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
09:14:09  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
09:14:09  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
09:14:09  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

This is the last entry in the error log:

```
2020-08-06  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-08-06  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-08-06  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-08-06  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-08-06  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-08-06  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-08-06  9:10:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-08-06  9:10:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-08-06  9:10:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-08-06  9:10:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\Environment\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-08-06  9:10:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\Environment\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-08-06  9:10:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-08-06  9:10:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 40471727; transaction id 36256
2020-08-06  9:10:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Environment\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-08-06  9:10:28 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-08-06  9:10:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200806  9:10:28
2020-08-06  9:10:28 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I have already checked the port (3306): Nothing is blocking it. I have no other instances of MySQL running on my computer. Neither in the Task-Manager nor in the services.msc. But just to be sure I changed the port for MySql to 3308, but it still wouldn't start.

I also tried deleting `ibdata1, ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1,ib_logfile101` in `xampp/mysql/data`.

The last thing I tried was [setting up IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208744/how-to-configure-mysql-under-xampp-to-work-with-ipv6) which I know was a hail mary.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11013868/11824001

And then following the error messages I was getting in PhPMyAdmin.
Turns out my mysql.db table was corrupted and had to be repaired with:

`use mysql`

`repair table db;`